# How comes a GitLab CI/CD job cant' find its artifacts?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, linux

In the [Open Source ventilator project](https://gitlab.com/open-source-ventilator/ventilator), we aim to provide those who focus on testing with a ready-to-go flash file for the Arduino controller board.

While the binaries seem to be there, for some reason the CI job can't pickup the artifacts.

What is happening:

- a CI/CD pipeline creates two files which can be listed using `find`
- in the next step, this pipeline reports it can't find these artifacts. It says, "no matching files/no files to upload".

What's the error and how to fix/troubleshoot? Why does this job end up as successful?

[CI job definition](https://gitlab.com/open-source-ventilator/ventilator/controller_ci/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
compile:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    -  |

        git clone -b ci-gh https://github.com/mattd3v/Open-Source-Ventilator.git
        cd Open-Source-Ventilator/OpenSourceVentilator/
        arduino-cli compile --warnings all --fqbn arduino:avr:uno -o osv-controller-uno.bin OpenSourceVentilator.ino
        find .
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./osv-controller-uno.bin.hex
    - ./osv-controller-uno.bin.elf
```

[Pipeline output](https://gitlab.com/open-source-ventilator/ventilator/controller_ci/-/jobs/507996642):

```
.
./test
./test/RMVS_TestCaseData.xlsx
./OpenSourceVentilator.ino
./osv-controller-uno.bin.hex
./osv-controller-uno.bin.elf
./README.md

section_end:1586713988:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1586713988:after_script
[0;msection_end:1586713990:after_script
[0Ksection_start:1586713990:archive_cache
[0K[0K[36;1m Saving cache[0;m
[0;msection_end:1586713991:archive_cache
[0K section_start:1586713991:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K [0K [36;1m

Uploading artifacts for successful job[0;m
[0;m[32;1m
Uploading artifacts...[0;m

[0;33m WARNING: ./osv-controller-uno.bin.hex: no matching files[0;m 
[0;33m WARNING: ./osv-controller-uno.bin.elf: no matching files[0;m 

[31;1mERROR: No files to upload                         [0;m 
section_end:1586713993:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K[32;1mJob succeeded
[0;m
```

Comment: I assume the runner uses the root of the build dir. I would try `- Open-Source-Ventilator/OpenSourceVentilator/osv-controller-uno.bin.hex`

Answer (score 1):

As Casey Vega commented: provide the complete path.